# Getting error ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, ora-00936

When I trying the below SQL I am getting the error ORA-00936: missing expression. Please help me on this, I want distinct on those to columns in Oracle SQL

```
SELECT rr.RPT_QUE_I, 
       DISTINCT (rr.ed_sbmt_m, rr.RPT_RUN_STAT_C),
       rr.rpt_cstm_x,
       rr.rpt_cmplt_m,
       CASE 
         WHEN rr.rpt_run_stat_c = 25453 THEN 'PENDING' 
         WHEN rr.rpt_run_stat_c = 25454 THEN 'ACTIVE' 
         WHEN rr.rpt_run_stat_c = 25455 THEN 'FINISHED' 
         WHEN rr.rpt_run_stat_c = 25458 THEN 'ERROR' 
         WHEN rr.rpt_run_stat_c = 25460 THEN 'SCHEDULED' 
       END,
       cc.pro_sym_I,
       rr.usr_wad_ownr_i 
  FROM audit_REPORT_RUN rr, 
       CLIENT_COMPANY cc
 WHERE rr.ED_SBMT_M > TO_DATE('06/01/2012','mm/dd/yyyy') 
   AND rr.ED_SBMT_M < TO_DATE('07/01/2012','mm/dd/yyyy') 
   AND rr.ORG_I = cc.ORG_I
ORDER BY rr.RPT_QUE_I
```

Comment: I don't recall `DISTINCT` working like that on Oracle -- looks like a PostgreSQL query you lifted and tried to use on Oracle.

Comment: Ok, now how can I get distinct records on those two cloumns, can you prase the query for me...

Comment: Please show table structure, sample data, and desired output -- build a fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com) if you can...

Comment: @user1958780: You can't have two columns from a table returned in a single column -- nevermind distinct values.  Remove the distinct and brackets, then start working with what you have.

Comment: What is the DISTINCT mean here? Does it mean there could be two rows that have the same rr.ed_sbmt_m and rr.RPT_RUN_STAT_C, but have different value on other columns like rr.rpt_run_stat_c? If this true, how do you want to handle these differences?

Answer (score 5):

You should use `DISTINCT` keyword at first after the `SELECT` keyword, and remove the parenthesis,
or if you need to categorize some of it, use `GROUP BY` functions. hope you're getting the desired result.